# Adding a user image to jquery ui auto-complete in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

i just successfully adding the jquery ui autocomplete widget to search functionality in my rails app and it work fine :). here is my code

The javascript

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$('#search').autocomplete({
 minLength: 1,
 source: "<%= list_path(:json) %>",

 focus: function(event, ui){
   $('#search').val(ui.item.user_name);
   return false;
 },
 select: function(event, ui){
 $('#search').val(ui.item.user_name);
 return false;
 }
})

.data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul,item){
  return $("<li></li>")
  .data("item.autocomplete",item)
  .append("<a>" + item.first_name + " " + item.last_name + "<br>" + item.user_name  +  "</a>" )
  .appendTo(ul);
};

});
```

The controller action

```
 def list
 list = []
 @user = User.where("user_name LIKE ? or first_name LIKE ? or last_name LIKE ?",   "#{params[:term]}%" , "#{params[:term]}%" , "#{params[:term]}%")
@user.each{|user| list << user}

respond_to do |format|
format.json { render :json => list.to_json,:layout=>false }
end
end
```

so basically the javascript invokes the action after every letter typed in the search box and then the result is appended to the html view.

but i want add more by including not just first_name,last_name and user_name but also user_image

i have tried getting the image from inside the javascript using the result returned 
eg

```
   <script>
      .
      .
      .
     // somwhere inside my javascript code
     var id = item.id
   <% @image= UserImage.find(:first,:conditions=>["user_id=?",id]) %>
      .
      .
    </script>
```

then i tried to append the image along with user_name,first_name etc 
eg

```
         <script>
           .
           . 
           .
        .append("<a>"+ <%=image_tag(@image.image.url(:thumb))%> + " " + tem.first_name + " " + item.last_name + "<br>" + item.user_name + "</a>" )
         <script>
```

but it didnt work...sigh

I was wondering if i can somehow add the image path in json (from my controller) then just append it in the javascript file

pls help :(

Answer (score 1):

i did a try and use paperclip to store image for user i got this :

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#user_name').autocomplete({
   minLength: 1,
   source: "<%= users_path(:json) %>",

   focus: function(event, ui){
    $('#user_name').val(ui.item.name);
    return false;
   },
   select: function(event, ui){
    $('#user_name').val(ui.item.name);
    return false;
   }
  })

  .data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul,item){
   return $("<li></li>")
  .data("item.autocomplete",item)
  .append("<a>"+"<img src='" + item.avatar_url +"'>"  + item.first_name + " " + item.last_name + "<br>" + item.name  +  "</a>" )
  .appendTo(ul);
  };
});
```

user.rb

```
def self.search (search_name)
 return scoped unless search_name.present?
  where(['name LIKE ? or first_name LIKE ? or last_name LIKE ?', "%#{search_name}%", "%#{search_name}%",  "%#{search_name}%"])
end
def avatar_url
 self.avatar.url :thumb
end
```

users_controller.rb

```
def index
if params[:name]
  @users = User.search(params[:name])
else
  @users = User.all
end
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @users.as_json(only: [:first_name, :last_name, :name], methods: [:avatar_url] )}
end
```

end

here the full code : https://github.com/senayar/autocompletion_image_paperclip

edited according to jvnill

Answer (score 1):

you have to change a couple of files

```
# controller
def list
  @users = User.where("user_name LIKE :q or first_name LIKE :q or last_name LIKE :q", { q: "#{params[:term]}%")

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: @users.as_json(only: [:first_name, :last_name, :user_name], methods: [:avatar_url] }
  end
end

# user.rb
def avatar_url
  user_image.image.url :thumb
end

# js
.data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul,item){
  return $("<li></li>")
    .data("item.autocomplete",item)
    .append("<a>" + item.first_name + " " + item.last_name + "<br>" + item.user_name  +  "</a>" )
    .append("<img src='" + item.avatar_url + "'>")
    .appendTo(ul);
}
```

Comment: if i read his code, thoses images user are store into user_images table.

Comment: yep that's why you have the `avatar_url` method to fetch the image you want. i'm assuming that he has a `has_one` association so just using `user_image.image.url` will suffice.